# row norms of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $A$ is symmetric positive definite. Is there any relationship between the row norm (excluding the diagonal)
$$
\left( \sum_{j\neq i} |A_{i,j}|^p \right)^{1/p}
$$
and the diagonal entry $A_{i,i}$?

For instance, if $A$ were diagonally dominant and $p=1$, then we know the row norm is bounded by the diagonal entry. But not all positive definite matrices are diagonally dominant and I would like a property which holds for all positive definite matrices.

Comment: I guess that the row norm should be the max over $i$ of this expression. Also, it does not seem to be a norm since we would not have $||A||=0$ implies $A=0$. Finally, if we ignore those points, a relationship does not exist with the diagonal entry only in general. While this true in the strictly diagonally dominant case, this will not be in the general case as the positive definiteness is a nonlinear property of the elements of the matrix; e.g. through the positivity of all its leading principal minors.

Comment: At the very least, this "row norm" can't be too large compared to the norm of the matrix. For $p = 1$, if $N_i$ is your row norm excluding the diagonal entry, then clearly $N_i \le \|A\|_{\infty} - A_{ii}$.